# Husky Simulator in kinetic

Tags: ros, husky, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've simulated Husky in Ubuntu 16. But there is something seems to be wrong.

The Husky packages  for Kinetic are downloaded from [here](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel).

When I execute

```
 $ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch
```

Gazebo will start. The interface of it and all models seem to be normal. However, error messages will come up in Terminal, like this :

```
[ERROR] [1500815218.577764934, 1298.710000000]: Could not load class joint_state_controller/JointStateController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin joint_state_controller/JointStateController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists. 
[ERROR] [1500815218.577845132, 1298.710000000]: Could not load controller 'husky_joint_publisher' because controller type 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' does not exist.
 [ERROR] [1500815218.577869881, 1298.710000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types [ERROR] [1500815219.578684, 1299.710000]: Failed to load husky_joint_publisher 
[ERROR] [1500815219.617019944, 1299.750000000]: Could not load class diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists. 
[ERROR] [1500815219.617082514, 1299.750000000]: Could not load controller 'husky_velocity_controller' because controller type 'diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1500815219.617099894, 1299.750000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
 [ERROR] [1500815220.618012, 1300.740000]: Failed to load husky_velocity_controller
```

Then execute

```
 $ roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch
```

There will be something wrong in rviz  with the model's all four wheels :

Display--RobotModel--StateError--front_left_wheel_link--No transform from [front_left_wheel_link] to [odm]

Are  there anyway to solve this problem???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269119/husky-simulator-in-kinetic/) by [JohnBT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31607/johnbt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-19**:
@JohnBT: please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) for console copy-pastes (including code, xml, errors, urdf) next time. Without it, error msgs are filtered (and thus invisible) and other text with formatting will not render correctly.

Thanks.

**Comment by [JohnBT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31607/johnbt/) on 2017-08-19**:
Got it.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From:

> ```
> [ERROR] [1500815218.577764934, 1298.710000000]: Could not load class joint_state_controller/JointStateController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin joint_state_controller/JointStateController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
> ```

```
[ERROR] [1500815218.577845132, 1298.710000000]: Could not load controller 'husky_joint_publisher' because controller type 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' does not exist.
 [ERROR] [1500815218.577869881, 1298.710000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types [ERROR] [1500815219.578684, 1299.710000]: Failed to load husky_joint_publisher 
[ERROR] [1500815219.617019944, 1299.750000000]: Could not load class diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists. 
[ERROR] [1500815219.617082514, 1299.750000000]: Could not load controller 'husky_velocity_controller' because controller type 'diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController' does not exist.
```

I get the impression that you don't have the `ros_controllers` package(s) installed.

> The Husky packages for Kinetic are downloaded from [here](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel).

Have you made sure to install all required dependencies?

Simply cloning that repository is *not enough*.

Please run

```
rosdep update
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws
rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src
```

That will most likely install packages like `ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller` and `ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller`.

Then try again.

---

Note btw that the `husky` packages have not been released yet into Kinetic, so even if things build correctly, it may still not work due to changes in some of the dependencies (Gazebo is v2 on Indigo fi, but v7 on Kinetic, and there have been many changes between those two versions).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2